# NMAP -PS, -PA options

Tags: sockets, packet, nmap

I'm beginner in using map and I read reference guide in nmap homepage. When I read host discovery with `-P*` options I suddenly had question about it.

There are `-PS` option in nmap and it sends `syn` packet to server to determine server is turned on or not. If nmap gets `ACK/SYN` packet for three-way handshake then it means server is turned on. If nmap get `RST` then it means that server is shut down. If timeout occur then firewall is exist between server and user computer...

Nmap homepage guide book saids they give `-PA` option to give more change for bypassing firewall. I thought if we send `ACK` packet instead of `SYN` then server will send `RST` packet for response in both case. Server is turned on or not. If timeout occur then we can determine firewall is exist. So I think usage of `-PA` is check firewall instead of check server is turned on or not.

My question is that I'm not sure about above things. Because I'm not good at network yet and beginner in this area. Did I understand correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the `-P*` options, Nmap considers any response from the server to be an indication that the server is up. Both `SYN/ACK` and `RST` packets count, as do several types of ICMP response like Port Unreachable. The specific type of response may indicate the state of the port, and would be analyzed by the port scan (`-s*` options), but for host discovery, any response is as good as another.